# request.getRemoteAddr() return server ip

Tags: java, rest, api, ip

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/origin/test/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String getTest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String Text = "Version - " + org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString();
    return Text+request.getRemoteAddr()+"----"+request.getLocalAddr();
}
```

In above code when running in the server it return server ip as remote address and also local address. 
But when running as localhost i have made a request with different laptop it return that laptop IP correctly. 
But the problem is server not returning the IP of laptop that made the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getRemoteAddr()` will cause trouble if the client is behind any proxy then you will get the IP address of the proxy

And when the client is using DHCP then the IP address can and will change during the session.

> getRemoteAddr(): Returns the Internet Protocol (IP) address of the client or last proxy that sent the request.

Answer (score 0):

Please updated it again use request.getRemoteAddr()

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/origin/test/", method = RequestMethod.GET, headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String getTest(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
    String Text = "Version - " + org.hibernate.Version.getVersionString();
    return Text+request.getRemoteAddr()+"----"+request.getRemoteAddr();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean @son pham

Comment: If you use nginx in config location you must add: proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  when you use request.getRemoteAddr() it will return IP client.

Comment: This is because some proxy. I have use the ip of server now it running perfectly. The server url was a shorten one. That is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NGINX standard settings, i.e.

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

You can use following call to get the IP as string:

```
String userIp = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
```